# Как узнать последний статус активности собеседника через Telegram API?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Есть ли способ узнать последний статус активности собеседника через Telegram API (тот же самый Telethon или любая другая библиотека)?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете узнать последний статус активности только в случае, если он не скрыт настройками конфиденциальности. В Telegram API для этого есть метод [contacts.getStatuses](https://core.telegram.org/method/contacts.getStatuses). В Telethon эту информацию можно получить используя метод [get_entity()](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html), он возвращает объект класса User, в случае если это пользователь, который имеет атрибут "status".